# Spring SpelExpression doesn't seem to read my bean when using @PreAuthorize

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I am trying to use @PreAuthorize but need to configure it to such that different environments has different access, but when I try and use @PreAuthorize("hasAuthority(#bean)") nothing get read into the authority.

I've tried using #bean and @bean but neither worked, but if I have a hard coded string there it works fine.
When Using #bean nothing gets passed in, and when using @bean I get  `No bean resolver registered in the context to resolve access to bean 'readRole'`

```
    @Bean
    public String readRole() {
        return "Domain Users";
    }

    @Target({ ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.TYPE })
    @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
    @PreAuthorize("hasAuthority(@readRole)")
    public @interface UserCanSeeRestricted { }
```

Then in my rest controller:

```
    @SecurityConfigExample.UserCanSeeRestricted
    @GetMapping("/all")
    public Collection<Office> getAllOffices()
    {
        return officeService.getAll();
    }
```

I want to be able to use the readRole to return different groups based on the environment and have them read by the @PreAuthorize

What I tried:

```
public class SecurityConfig {
        public String readRole = "Domain Users";
    }
    @Bean
    public SecurityConfig readRole() {
        return new SecurityConfig();
    }

    @Target({ ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.TYPE })
    @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
    @PreAuthorize("hasAuthority(@readRole.readRole)")
    public @interface UserCanSeeRestricted { }
```

--- Updated 2nd time:

```
    public class SecurityConfig {
        public String readRole() {
            return "Domain Users";
        }
    }
    @Bean
    public SecurityConfig readRole() {
        return new SecurityConfig();
    }

    @Target({ ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.TYPE })
    @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
    @PreAuthorize("hasAuthority(@readRole.readRole())")
    public @interface UserCanSeeRestricted { }
```

I tried replacing

```
    @SecurityConfigExample.UserCanSeeRestricted
```

with

```
@PreAuthorize("hasAuthority(@readRole.readRole())")
```

and it did not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I found was:

```
@Target({ ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.TYPE })
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@PreAuthorize("hasAnyAuthority(#root.getThis().getProps().getWriteRole())")
public @interface UserCanEditRestricted { }
```

Each of my controllers had to have a props object which stored the roles. This way the role is configurable.